# URL-Link over the side edge

Tags: urls

I do a manuel bibliography (not using bibtex or sth. like that) and I want to put some URL in it. But some of the URL are over the side edge.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,slashbox,graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[top=25mm, left=25mm, right=50mm, bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{acronym}
 %verlinkt mir Inhaltsverzeichnis, abkürzungsverzeichnis etc.
\usepackage{booktabs} %für Tabellen
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
%everything works fine
\section*{Literaturverzeichnis}
\noindent Corbet, S.; Meegan, A.; Larkin, C.; Lucey, B. und Yarovaya, L. (2018): Exploring the dynamic relationships between cryptocurrencies and other financial assets. Economics Letters, Vol. 165, S. 28-34, in: \url{https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/321DB6FE9DA3528B4C7477C4F104A4DCBF0AC14D8FCC0E9E1FED3C575B50FC25FDBBCF7FC7C8305801B8B6EC4A2D58DB}, abgerufen am 05.06.2018.\\ 
\end{document}
```

How can I divide the Link? I have a few of them looking over the edge. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

With `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` the url can only be broken at hyphens, which your url does not contain, thus it can not be broken.

Using the `xurl` package instead offers much more possible breaking points:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,slashbox,graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[top=25mm, left=25mm, right=50mm, bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{acronym}
 %verlinkt mir Inhaltsverzeichnis, abkürzungsverzeichnis etc.
\usepackage{booktabs} %für Tabellen
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
%everything works fine
\section*{Literaturverzeichnis}
\noindent Corbet, S.; Meegan, A.; Larkin, C.; Lucey, B. und Yarovaya, L. (2018): Exploring the dynamic relationships between cryptocurrencies and other financial assets. Economics Letters, Vol. 165, S. 28-34, in: \url{https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/321DB6FE9DA3528B4C7477C4F104A4DCBF0AC14D8FCC0E9E1FED3C575B50FC25FDBBCF7FC7C8305801B8B6EC4A2D58DB}, abgerufen am 05.06.2018.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if I write \usepackage{xurl}      i get file´xurl.xty´not found. How can i fix it?

Comment: @florian It is a pretty new package (released last December), so you may have to update your tex distribution

Comment: I just did an update. now I have version TeXstudio 2.12.8 I still get the same error message

Comment: @florian Texstudion is your editor. You need to update your distribution, typically something like miktex or texlive.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. I just did an Update of my Miktex. Thank you very much.